# WCF Reuse not working properly

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

I've been now for several hours trying to figure out a way to share my Entity classes between the WCF Service and the Client. The problem is when I select "Reuse types in referenced assemblies", my Service Reference comes completely empty. I have two service contracts:

```
public class ServiceUser : Service<User>, IServiceUser
{
    public ServiceUser()
    {
        AtcContext context = new AtcContext();
        Set = context.Users;
    }

    public virtual User Validate(string userName, string hashPassword)
    {
        UserValidator userValidator = new UserValidator();
        userValidator.Validate(userName, hashPassword);

        return userValidator.AuthenticatedUser;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ServiceEmployee : Service<Employee>, IServiceEmployee
{
    public ServiceEmployee()
    {
        Context = new AtcContext();
        Set = Context.Employees;
    }

    public Employee GetSingleBySequence(string sequence)
    {
        Employee entity = Set.Where(e => e.Sequence == sequence).FirstOrDefault();

        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new BdlFramework.Exceptions.BdlEntryNotFoundException();
        }

        return entity;
    }

    public Employee GetSingleByName(string FirstName, string LastName)
    {
        Employee entity = Set.Where(e => e.FirstName == FirstName && e.LastName == LastName).FirstOrDefault();

        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new BdlFramework.Exceptions.BdlEntryNotFoundException();
        }

        return entity;
    }

    public int GetNextSequence()
    {
        try
        {
            return Set.Where(e => SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(e.Sequence) > 0).Select(e => e.Sequence).Cast<int>().Max() + 1;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

An entity looks a bit like this:

```
public class User : BaseKeyEntity
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Employee")]
    [DataMember]
    public new int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._Id != value)
            {
                this._Id = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _UserName = "";
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    [Index("IX_User_UserName", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._UserName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._UserName != value)
            {
                this._UserName = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("UserName");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Big part of the entity code is suppressed).

Anyone has an idea of what is going on here?

Comment: We had this same problem... never really got it to work with the `Reuse types in referenced assemblies`, what we ended up doing was making sure our Entities were separated into their own project, and referencing that project in both the client and the server.

Comment: I figured out that the Entities used by ServiceContracts had to be completely serializable. Then it worked.